# Has there been an issue with keyframing the alpha channel of a material when rendering in the GPU since 2.9.0?

Tags: python, rendering, animation, gpu

I am trying to depict the "disappearance" of meshes via a decrease in their alpha channels. The animation is done using a python script and cycles. The problem arises during render of the animation into discrete PNGs. When rendering in the CPU of any computer, the animation comes out as expected, but when the GPU is enabled (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070), the orbitals come out pixelated (2.90.1) and don't get animated (the alpha channel at least, the orbitals still move) at all (2.93.1).

Follows an image of the orbitals during the fade out animation using 2.90.1:
[image: Image rendered on GPU]

To generate the frames, the following command line command was used:

```
blender -b iso.blend -P main.py
```

Where iso.blend is the blender file with the camera positioned and two random materials already created and main.py is the script below:

```
import mathutils;
import bpy;
import numpy as np;
import os;
import re;
import sys;
import json;
directory = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath);
if not dir in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(directory);

#The following commands tells blender to use the gpu
# enable GPUs
known_devices = [r'GeForce RTX 2070 with Max-Q Design',r'GeForce GTX 1080 Ti',r'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070', r'GeForce GTX 970']
cuda_devices = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.get_devices()
print(cuda_devices)
bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
gpu_found = False
for device in bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.devices:
    if device.name in known_devices:
        device.use = True
        print('Enabling: %s' % device.name)
        gpu_found = True
    else:
        device.use = False
    
#MAKING THE ANIMATION #####################################################
def set_active(obj):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj;

def get_active():
    return bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
    
def select(*obj):
    [o.select_set(True) for o in obj]

def deselect():
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = "DESELECT")



def animate_alpha(obj):
    init = 1
    end = 0
    for t0 in np.arange(0, 10)*10:
        transition = 5
        for m in obj.material_slots:
            mat = m.material
            material = m.material
            imp = material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[18]
            imp.default_value = init
            imp.keyframe_insert("default_value", frame = t0)
            imp.default_value = end
            imp.keyframe_insert("default_value", frame = t0 + transition)
            imp.default_value = init
            imp.keyframe_insert("default_value", frame = t0 + transition*2)

    
N = 6
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi*2 - 2*np.pi/N, N)
r = 1.5
x = np.cos(theta)*r
y = np.sin(theta)*r
coords = np.vstack((x, y, x*0)).T

meshes = []
for c in coords:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=c, radius = .4)
    ball = get_active()
    ball.active_material = bpy.data.materials.get("positive")
    deselect()
    animate_alpha(ball)
    meshes.append(ball)
    
deselect()
bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
dummy = get_active()
select(*meshes)
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type="OBJECT")

deselect()
select(dummy)
set_active(dummy)
dummy.rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
dummy.keyframe_insert("rotation_quaternion", frame = 0)
dummy.rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Quaternion([0, 0, 1], np.pi/2)
dummy.keyframe_insert("rotation_quaternion", frame = 100)


# Setting up the defatult rendering properties
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].view_settings.gamma = .92;
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.film_transparent = True;
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 512
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 512
bpy.context.scene.render.tile_x = 512/2
bpy.context.scene.render.tile_y = 512/2
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 60
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.file_format = "PNG"
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.color_mode = "RGBA"

for i in range(120):
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), str(i).zfill(3));
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_current = i;
    bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still=True)
```

Note that this script is simpler than the original, as it only shows the spheres. But the error persists in this version.